# What is the best way of appending dataframes in R in case column names are not known beforehand?

Tags: r

I usually do either this

```
initflag <- FALSE
for (i in range(10)) {
  datafragment <- <some processing of data fragment>
  if (!initflag){
    mydf <- datafragment
    initflag <- TRUE
  }
  mydf <- rbind(mydf, datafragment)
```

}
or assigning a zero-length copy of first fragment to `mydf` before entering the loop, effectively copying all column names.